# How to like a comment on a post through the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to like comments on posts through the Facebook API and if so, how? I haven't found anything in the documentation, only similar SO questions but they are almost ten years old and might be outdated by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Earlier, it was only used/abused for autoliking and like selling platforms, so they removed the possibility.